# understanding overlaying process image and execl call

Tags: c, debugging, ptrace

I want to build my own debugger, from scratch, so I am trying to pick up some of the concepts behind it. First, I am starting easy, using the ptrace library. But even at this point I am having some issues, let me run through this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pid_t child_pid;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected a program name as argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
        run_target(argv[1]);
    else if (child_pid > 0)
        run_debugger(child_pid);
    else {
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is nothing really special, I am creating a child process using fork()
the next function is what really I cannot understand

```
void run_target(const char* programname)
{
    procmsg("target started. will run '%s'\n", programname);

    /* Allow tracing of this process */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0) {
        perror("ptrace");
        return;
    }

    /* Replace this process's image with the given program */
    execl(programname, programname, 0);
}
```

The last call is the issue. this call represents the concept of overlaying process image.I am not fully getting what is happening. This is what the author says:

> I've highlighted the part that interests us in this example. Note that the very next  thing run_target does after ptrace is invoke the program given to it as an argument
>  with execl. This, as the highlighted part explains, causes the OS kernel to stop the  process just before it begins executing the program in execl and send a signal to the  parent.

To run the debugger basically the parent process must trace the child process, which acknowledges that it wants to be traced using PTRACEME. But I can’t figure out what that execl is doing. I can understand the purpose and the output but can’t figure out HOW. I consulted the man pages but could not wrap my head around this.
I would appreciate if someone could give me a clear explanation of what’s going on with this execl function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between fork and exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/differences-between-fork-and-exec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you agree on this: the concept is that the debugger must debug program `TARGET`, that can only be debugged if it calls `PTRACE_TRACEME`.

Naturally, `TARGET` does not call `ptrace` with `PTRACE_TRACEME` argument in its source code.
So, the debugger must do it for it.

Initially, the debugger forks. At this time we have two processes:

1. Father: it calls `run_debugger()`
2. Child: it calls `run_target()`

Child is a process that the debugger has control on it, therefore it can call ptrace with argument `PTRACE_TRACEME` (in `run_target()`). But this process is not `TARGET`.

Thus, next step is associating to `child` the "image" of `TARGET` (namely the program we want to debug). A process image is an executable file required while executing the program, and it's composed of the 4 classical segments:

1. Code (text segment)
2. Data
3. Stack
4. Heap

`execl` and friends belong to exec family, namely functions which replace the current process image with a new process image. `execl` differs from its friend `execv` for the way the arguments are passed to the best of my knowledge, but the concept is the same.

So, what you need to know is that:

> `exec` replaces the currently running program by another program (i..e., `TARGET`)
> inside an **EXISTING** process.

The latter has called `ptrace` with argument `PTRACE_TRACEME` so the new program will not ignore the future ptrace calls made by the debugger.

If your question is the implementation details of `exec` systemcall, I have not a perfect knowledge for it, but I can give some suggestions:

- Reading *"The exec-like Functions"* in the book *"Understanding Linux Kernel"*
- Having a look to the source code ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689724/where-do-i-find-the-source-code-for-execve)) directionates you to the source code of `execve` which is totally fine for you, same concept of `execl`.
- If you want to create your own exec, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761965/passing-arguments-to-own-execv-kernel-implementation) can be useful as well.

Comment: thanks man a tad late but great answer :)